# How does the onLoadFinished callback get a cursor?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, loader

How does the `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor)` callback method receive a cursor?

Also, what's the standard way to not receive a stale cursor after changes to the data source? Most recently, I've used:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
```

Not sure if using `restartLoader()` is the correct way.

Comment: are you using `ContentProvider` and `CursorLoader`? then you don't need to call `restartLoader` ... all you need to do is notify the uri which was passed to the `CursorLoader` constructor from all methods of the CP which modifying the data(`insert/update/delete`)(of course cursor should be registered for notification right before you return it from `CP.query`)

Comment: Yes, I am using a ContentProvider and CursorLoader. Also, I'm notifying the uri's and register my cursor. I still get a stale cursor in onLoadFinished() if i don't call restartLoader(). Doesn't seem right to me, though.